# Adding Name and year Bracket to reference list

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I'm new to LaTeX, and using `natbib` to handle my citations:

```
\usepackage[authoryear,square]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{authordate1}
\bibliography{sample}
```

Now my citations inside the article looks fine [author, year], but when the reference list is shown at the end I want the same [author, year] cell to be next to each reference.
How can I do that ?

Here is MWEB example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[authoryear,square]{natbib}

\usepackage{filecontents}    
\begin{filecontents}{sample.bib}
@article{lorenz1963,
  title={Deterministic nonperiodic flow},
  author={Lorenz, Edward N},
  journal={Journal of the atmospheric sciences},
  volume={20},
  number={2},
  pages={130--141},
  year={1963}
}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}  
\citep{lorenz1963}
\bibliographystyle{authordate1}
\bibliography{sample}
\end{document}
```

Thank you !

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which document class do you use?

Comment: Thanks ! I'm using : `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}`

Comment: Incidentally, *why* would you wish to have these completely useless strings clutter up the formatted bibliography?

Comment: Please show not only a code snippet but a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography). This would help us to reproduce and understand the problem and to test our suggestions before posting them. So it would help us to help you. Nevertheless, for new documents I would recommend to use `biblatex` + `biber` instead of the old `bibtex` system, because it is better configurable.

Comment: I think it would be easier to find the full reference of the citation that way (and I don't want to use numbers in the article)

Comment: I've taken the liberty of making your example code compilable. With `natbib` in use, the citation callout will be `[Lorenz, 1963]` and the formatted bib entry will be `Lorenz, Edward N. 1963. ...` Honestly, if you can't trust your readers to be able to figure out how to associate the call-outs with the appropriate bib entries, you are in deep, deep trouble: Your readers will likely not understand a single word of your entire document. Is this a realistic concern?

Comment: Thank you! I'm writing my first time now, so I want to know at least how to do it - maybe I wont use it, but it is still good to know

Answer (score 3):

One can take advantage that the format of the `.bbl` file will be

```
\bibitem[\protect\citename{Lorenz, }1963]{lorenz1963}
```

so we can use the part in brackets to become the beginning of the citation text.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{lorenz1963,
  title={Deterministic nonperiodic flow},
  author={Lorenz, Edward N},
  journal={Journal of the atmospheric sciences},
  volume={20},
  number={2},
  pages={130--141},
  year={1963}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[authoryear,square]{natbib}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \let\natbibbibitem\bibitem
  \let\bibitem\valientbibitem
}
\makeatletter
\def\valientbibitem[#1]#2{%
  \natbibbibitem[#1]{#2}%
  \begingroup\let\citename\@firstofone
  [#1]
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}  

\citep{lorenz1963}

\bibliographystyle{authordate1}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I agree with the comments saying this is just cluttering the bibliography.

---

During testing, I discovered that there is a bug in `authordate1.bst` that causes a spurious space that's added when “et al.” appears in a citation callout.

This can only be cured by fixing the source. Make a copy of `authordate1.bst` calling it `authordate1-fix.bst` in the working directory. In it change all occurrences of

```
{\em et~al.\ }\relax
```

into

```
{\em et~al\@.}\relax
```

In your document do `\bibliographystyle{authordate1-fix}`.

Answer (score 1):

You could

- *not* load the `natbib` package, and
- provide a dummy definition for `\citename`, and
- use `\cite` instead of `\citep` to generate the citation call-outs.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}    
\begin{filecontents}{sample.bib}
@article{lorenz1963,
  title={Deterministic nonperiodic flow},
  author={Lorenz, Edward N.},
  journal={Journal of the Atmospheric Sciences},
  volume={20},
  number={2},
  pages={130--141},
  year={1963}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
%\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib} % don't load natbib
\providecommand\citename[1]{#1}  % provide a dummy definition

\begin{document}  
\cite{lorenz1963}                % <-- use \cite, not \citep
\bibliographystyle{authordate1}
\bibliography{sample}
\end{document}
```